Struggling to reconcile definition of surface integral with physical situations
I have a confusion about how only including the component of a vector field normal to a surface in surface integrals gives the intuitively correct answer in certain physical situations.
I saw in an answer to this question that, when we consider a vector field $\mathbf{v}$ moving across a surface $S$ on the infinitesimal level, we see that it is only the component of $\mathbf{v}$ normal to $S$ that is actually moving across $S$. And that makes sense, in the abstract; but I am having trouble reconciling this reasoning with physical situations.
For example, suppose I spray a hose through a window at an angle. Then the fluid flow through the window will have a component normal to the plane of the window and a component parallel to the plane of the window - but that parallel component still contributes to the total fluid flow through the window. Moreover, the reasoning about the infinitesimal contributions seems to break down. If I only considered water from the hose perpendicular to the plane of the window in my calculation of how much water crosses the window, then I would get a different result for the surface integral of water across the window as I rotated the hose to various angles to change the component of fluid flow normal to the window. But that can’t be correct because we will always have the same amount of fluid flowing through the window.
So what is going on here? How is this not a counterexample to only using normal components in surface integrals?

In comparison with spraying water perpendicularly through the window, spraying it at an angle makes two differences. (1) The perpendicular component of the flow is now smaller, since there's also a parallel component. (2) The flow goes through  larger area of the window, because the window cuts the stream at an angle. These two differences cancel each other in the surface integral, so the integral givea the correct result: The same flow regardless of the angle.

No, the parallel component does not flow through the window, but merely along it. (Think of water flow tangent to a circle. Does it flow across?)
